# Getting Value of Multiple Selected Checkbox with Same Name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I can't seem to get the correct output. I am not sure if my for loop is the problem. Please excuse my variable names. I know I know, I made them very obvious.  :) By the way, should I use var here or let is fine?

I have read somewhere that when declaring a variable:

var => function-scoped

ES6 (ES2015): let, const => block-scoped

The check all button won't work as well.

Your input will be highly appreciated.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Get Checkbox Value</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      body {
          padding-top: 10px;
          font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
          background-color: #ede5e5;
          height: 100vh;
      }
      div { 
          width: 50%;
          margin: auto;
          border: 1px solid lightgray;
          border-radius: 5px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(34 36 38 / 15%);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(34 36 38 / 15%);
          padding: 10px;
          padding-left: 20px;
          padding-bottom: 30px;
          background-color: white;
      }
      button {
          padding:5px;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: bold;
      }
      label {
          font-size: 18px;
          font-weight: bold;
      }
      input [type=checkbox] {
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
      }

  </style>

 </head>
<body>
    <div style="">
      <h2>Select a Programming Language You Love</h2>
      <form id="frm-lang">
          
          <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="JavaScript">
          <label>JavaScript</label><br/>

          <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="PHP">
          <label>PHP</label><br/>

          <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Pyton">
          <label>Pyton</label><br/>

          <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="C#">
          <label>C#</label><br/>

          <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="C++">
          <label>C++</label><br/><br/>

          <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
          <button id="btnCheckAll">Check All</button>


      </form>


    </div>
     <script>
         let formvar = document.getElementById('frm-lang');  
         let valuesvar = [];

         formvar.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {   
          e.preventDefault ();
          let checkboxesvar = document.getElementsByName('languages');
          for (let i = 0; i < checkboxesvar.length; i++) {  
              if (checkboxesvar[i].checked == true) {  
              
                  valuesvar.push(checkboxesvar[i].value);  
              }   
          }

           alert('The values(s): ' + valuesvar.toString());
         });   

         // for the check all button

         document.getElementById('btnCheckAll').onclick = function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             let checkboxesvar = document.getElementsByName('languages');
             for (let i=0; i < checkboxesvar.length; i++) {
                 checkbboxesvar[i].checked = true;
             }
         }


            
     </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `submit` listener, you are not clearing your array, so it will keep the values from the previous submission, you need to clear it, so move it to inside the listener

in your `checkAll` you had a typo, `checbboxesvar` with 2 `b`

I improved your code a bit, renamed variable names and left one line solutions.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('frm-lang');
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('languages');
const checkAll = document.getElementById('btnCheckAll');
const clearAll = document.getElementById('btnClearAll');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let values = [];
  // for loop solution
  
  //for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  //  if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
  //    values.push(checkboxes[i].value);
  //  }
  //}
  
  //one liner solution
  checkboxes.forEach(el => el.checked &&  values.push(el.value))
 
 console.log('The values(s): ' + values);
});

// for the check all button

checkAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // for loop solution

  //for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  //  checkboxes[i].checked = true;
  //}

  //one liner solution
  checkboxes.forEach(el => el.checked = true)
})

clearAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // for loop solution

  //for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  //  checkboxes[i].checked = false;
  //}

  //one liner solution
  checkboxes.forEach(el => el.checked = false)
})
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ede5e5;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(34 36 38 / 15%);
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

button {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

label {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Select a Programming Language You Love</h2>
  <form id="frm-lang">

    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="JavaScript">
    <label>JavaScript</label><br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="PHP">
    <label>PHP</label><br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Pyton">
    <label>Pyton</label><br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="C#">
    <label>C#</label><br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="C++">
    <label>C++</label><br/><br/>

    <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnCheckAll">Check All</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnClearAll">Clear All</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you misspelled checkboxesvar your variable is checkboxesvar